# Java JSP - How to catch date exception using validator?

Tags: java, hibernate, spring, jsp

I need help. How can I trap the exception whenever the date field is left blank when a user forgot to input a birthDate. I used Validator interface to handle it. And I want Java to print on the browser when birthdate field is empty a message `FootballPlayer birth date is required.` What happens is that when the birthdate field is empty it prints out the Exception and the error message I created. It prints like this:

> Failed to convert property value of type java.lang.String to required type java.util.Date for property birthDate; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type [java.lang.String] to required type [java.util.Date] for property birthDate: no matching editors or conversion strategy found
>
> FootballPlayer birth date is required.

I only want to print `FootballPlayer birth date is required.`. How can I do this?

Im completely new to java and programming. Please help.

**FootballPlayerValidator.java:**

```
   if (footballPlayer.getBirthDate() == null || footballPlayer.getBirthDate().equals(null)) {
        try {
            errors.rejectValue("birthDate", null, null, "FootballPlayer birth date is required.");
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

**FootballPlayerController.java:**

```
@RequestMapping (value = "/add", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String saveFootballPlayer (@ModelAttribute ("footballPlayer") FootballPlayer footballPlayer,
        BindingResult result, Model model, HttpSession session) {
    System.out.println("Saving footballPlayer");
    footballPlayerValidator.validate(footballPlayer, result);
    if (result.hasErrors())
        return "addFootballPlayer";
    saveFootballPlayer(footballPlayer);
    return "successfullySaved";
}
```

In my setter and getter I declared birthdate as Date and also in my database.

**FootballPlayer.java:**

```
private Date birthDate;

public Date getBirthDate() {
    return birthDate;
}

public void setBirthDate(Date birthDate) {
    this.birthDate = birthDate;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
@NotNull
public Date getBirthDate() {
    return birthDate;
}
```

**EDIT :**

sorry I don't see that you don't use validation-api.

Comment: How can I use the annotation @NotNull. I mean how do I import?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using java.util.Date for the date object you need to ask spring to convert the string value from the jsp to a Date object; [here](http://robertmarkbramprogrammer.blogspot.com/2008/02/date-validation-in-spring-mvc.html) is a tutorial on how to do it

Later, you need to set the validation (which is what you are looking for); there is a sample for it [here](http://mdeinum.wordpress.com/2007/02/09/converting-string-to-date-and-date-formatting-in-spring-mvc/).